# What is the Google algorhythm when unpublishing apps?

Tags: android, google-play

Does anybody know about the Google algorhythm when unpublishing apps? I have an app with about 100.000 downloads. This was my first app and is 1 year old. I deleted my keystore-file accidently and couldnt update the app anymore. So I made a new version of this app and created a new app listing.

I changed the old app-store-text to inform people that they should download the new version. Downloads decreased from ~250 downloads per day to 100. But still these 100 should read my text and download my brand new app (with new features, bugfixes, etc.). So I'm thinking of unpublishing my old app, but I don't know if this is a smart move and wanted some suggestions and help about this first.

My question is: Would unpublishing the app affect my "status" or reputation as a developer, because it won't be in the app store anymore? You know these little badges like "Top Developer". I'm sure I'm far away from these, but I think that Google ranks apps of developers that already have successful apps higher than new developers or developers with less apps in the store like in this case when I'm unpublishing the app.

Comment: I don't think you have an option here. Just unpublish the old one if you think that people should not keep installing it; it is okay to do so because you have no choice. Next time, keep your keystore somewhere like in the cloud to avoid such mistakes!

Comment: Was it a major update ? If not you could keep both on the market until you find your keystore. You could lose downloads but not reputation quote. You will lose reputation if users write bad comments about your apps

Comment: Sorry, I forget to mention that I already uploaded the major updated app as a new app listing for about 1 month now. I have also good download on this new listing, but there are still many people downloading the old app. That is why I'm thinking of unpublishing it, but I just wanted to know if this would affect my developer status or reputation and if you know any inside information how Google handles that